# Is every device that converts electrical to mechanical energy considered an electric motor?

Tags: motor

I'm studying electroenergetic devices and we've been learning about the components of a motor, i.e. the stator and the rotor. But then I get reminded of ion propulsion technology used in rockets, where they speed up ions using electromagnetic fields which then move the rocket. Is that also an electrical motor?

Comment: A term with wider scope is "transducer" though this also covers anything that converts a physical parameter (one or more, actually) into electrical energy or visa versa. All things that mediate between physics and electrical signaling, in either direction, are transducers. Motors are transducers.

Comment: If you study EE, then you should be hearing about electric machines and electromechanical converters.

Comment: It depends on how broad you want your definition of "motor" to be.

Comment: A solenoid, a relay, or a buzzer converts electrical to mechanical energy. Not necessarily into horsepower, but into sound of usable motion.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Anything that converts chemical or electrical energy to mechanical motion or force is a ‘motor’. So, an ion propulsion device is indeed a motor: it uses electrical energy to do work on an ion stream, accelerating it to make the reaction force.

Answer (score 0):

"Motor" and "electric" are arbitrary terms that can be defined as you want to define them. Solenoids can be a motor, piezo devices can be motors and ion propulsion systems can be considered electric motors. Simply clarify your definition of electric motor before you use the term.

Note that an ion propulsion system needs a supply of an atom (or molecule?) that can be ionized and accelerated away from the craft to give an "equal and opposite reaction" - commonly the ionized atom is Xenon, if I remember correctly.

Comment: _"**arbitrary** terms that can be defined as **you** want to define them"_ - er...

Comment: If the definition of electric motor is so clear in your mind, why is this a question?  Right?  This is exactly why the body of a patent is required before the claims of the patent are made - to (hopefully) insure clarity of the terms and context  of those terms used in the claims of the patent.  The writer of the patent can define new terms in the body of a patent or redefine existing terms in the body of the patent or define that the terms of the art are "well known to anyone familiar with the art".  If someone wants to claim an ion engine is not an electric motor, that's their prerogative.

Comment: It shouldn't be a question. 5 seconds of googling is enough to confirm that the definition of electric motor is not 'arbitrary'.

Comment: Umm, instead of sniping my answer, why don't you post some links that you found in the 5-seconds of googling to guide the user to an answer about whether an ion thruster is/is not an "electric motor"?